# Why a stripped binary file can still have library call information in the disassembled file?

Tags: linux, compilation, linker, strip, symbol-table

test platform is 32 bit Linux.

I compile a c program **without  strip** the symbol information, and use objdump to 
disassembly the elf executable file.

Here is part of the results.

```
804831c:  e8 8c fe ff ff     call 8048360 <printf@plt>
```

If I use:

```
strip binary
```

to remove the symbol info and use objdump to disassembly the elf executable file again, I can still see the results like:

```
804831c:  e8 8c fe ff ff     call 8048360 <printf@plt>
```

So my question is:

How can disassembly tool like objdump know the name of certain library functions after I have stripped all the symbol information..?

Thank you!

Comment: printf is not a syscall

Comment: Sorry, I mean library call... @tristan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ELF file has 2 symbol tables: .symtab and .dynsym. The latter is for dynamic symbols needed for dynamic linking (relocation).
In your case, printf is in .dynsym and it may also be present in .symtab; by default strip would remove .symtab but not .dynsym which is needed for relocation.

You may try

> strip -R .dynsym your_binary

to remove the dynsym section manually and you will find it fails to run due to relocation failure.

Comment: THank you for your reply. But when I use **readelf -R test** to check the stripped elf binary's relocation table, it outputs nothing

Answer (score 2):

Imported calls will always have the name, it is needed to link at runtime. If you stripped the import name, how would your application know what to call? Methods from external libraries may (and usually do) have a different address every time your application is executed.

On another note, inlined or statically-linked methods can sometimes be identified and named even without symbol information. Many disassemblers look for common patterns associated with some standard library functions. `memcpy()` for example, can often be heuristically identified and labeled even without symbol info available.